# @AfterAll does not run at the end of all tests

Tags: junit5

I run the tests in parallel. And after running all the tests, the analysis check should start.

I can't understand why there is no execution of the general method after all the nodes of the test class are executed.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.parallel.Execution;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.parallel.ExecutionMode;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;


@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
public class FirstTest {

    private static List<String> threadNames = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());


    @AfterAll
    public static void afterAllTest() {

        Assumptions.assumeTrue(FirstTest::isParallelExecutionEnable);

        long count = threadNames.stream()
                .distinct()
                .count();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("count : " + count);

        assertThat(count).isEqualTo(2);
    }

    private static boolean isParallelExecutionEnable() {

        String ENABLED_PARALLEL_EXECUTION = "junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled";
        String PARALLELISM_FACTOR = "junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism";

        try {
            Properties junitConfig = new Properties();
            junitConfig.load(new ClassPathResource("junit-platform.properties").getInputStream());

            boolean enabled =
                    Boolean.valueOf(junitConfig.getProperty(ENABLED_PARALLEL_EXECUTION, "false"));

            if (!enabled) return false;

            int parallelismFactor =
                    Integer.valueOf(junitConfig.getProperty(PARALLELISM_FACTOR, "1"));

            int moreThanOneThread = 1;
            return parallelismFactor > moreThanOneThread;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Test
    void helloTest() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        threadNames.add(name);
        System.out.println("Hello! " + name);
    }

    @Test
    void worldTest() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        threadNames.add(name);
        System.out.println("World! " + name);
    }

}
```

- pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.javabydeveloper</groupId>
    <artifactId>Junit5-parallel-tests-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

        <!-- Dependency versions -->
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.5.2</junit.jupiter.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>

        <!-- Encoding -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I get no errors and the tests go well, but the runtime analysis doesn't work out.

Can someone explain why the last method marked with the @AfterAll annotation does not work ?

Comment: Please show your imports to rule out you’re mixing JUnit 4 and 5.

Comment: @johanneslink: I have pointed that.